# Some clarification regarding Android basics?

Tags: android

Am very new to Android development, Am totally confused about the following cases please help me.

I have read that each android application is a separate linux process

By default each android application is a single linux process

However we can start a separate process in an application for example:

We can run a service as separate process

And each process run in its own VM

If an application named "test" starts 2 processes servicePr1 and servicePr2 then how it will encapsulate to the application("test")

If we start two process each of them has separate VM? if So Will there is 3 VM including application ? How these all encapsulate to an application?

If we close the "test" will these two process servicePr1 and servicePr2 remains in the memory as separate process ?

Will these exist in the taskmanager ?

Encapsulation,  i mean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.so.test" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
     android:process="com.so.p1">
        <activity android:name=".Activity1">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:process="com.so.p2">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity3" android:process="com.so.p3">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here 3 process are started from one application

```
Activity1 runs in com.so.p1 process
Activity2 runs in com.so.p2 process
Activity3 runs in com.so.p3 process
```

**I read that each android process is run on separate VM.**

**When an application "test" started will there is four android process with four  VM with same UID?**

**If these 4 process run in separate VM how it can be said that it is an application(4 individual process)**

**Will these 4 process communicate with each other via IPC ?**

**While we quit the application what will happens to these processes  ? will three process remains in memory.**

Comment: This looks like a bit academic question. As per FAQ, you should ask questions about real problems you are facing and which you are trying to solve. Also, as far as I know, each Android app is a separate linux USER in the system, which means each app is ran in a sanbox of some sort - it cant access files of other users (apps) etc. More info here: http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/index.html

Comment: Each app is a separate user in Linux system, by default each application is assigned with unique id by the system. I agreed these all the things but please read my question if you can give the explanation it will be fruitful whether it is an academic question or not

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "encapsulate to an application" - as far as the kernel is concerned, there really is no such concept, though there may be some sense of tracking the processes together in the Android runtime code which manages state and decides what should live/die.

Comment: @Chris Stratton I have updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services started by an application can remain active without any activity, depending on how they are started and configured. As per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), there are two kinds of services: started services and bound services. For started services:

> A service is "started" when an application component (such as an activity) starts it by calling startService(). Once started, a service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

The task manager sees all running processes, so any running services will be visible.

I don't know what "encapsulate to an application" means, so I can't address that part of your question.

EDIT (to address edit to question)

This is covered in the guide topic [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

1. When an application "test" started will there is four android process with four VM with same UID?

   When the app in your sample manifest first starts, it will have two processes, one corresponding to the application and one corresponding to `Activity3` (the main launch component). If `Activity2` starts, it will run in a third process. If `Activity1` starts, it will run in the same process as the application itself.
2. If these 4 process run in separate VM how it can be said that it is an application (4 individual process)

   The components (activities, services, broadcast receivers, data providers) running in separate processes are part of the same application because internal bookkeeping in the Android system identifies the components as being part of the application. "Application" and "process" are orthogonal concepts in Android; an application can be spread across several processes and a process can be running components from different applications (provided the applications share the same Linux user ID and are signed with the same certificate).
3. Will these 4 process communicate with each other via IPC?

   Yes, processes communicate through IPC.
4. While we quit the application what will happens to these processes ? will three process remains in memory.

   That's entirely up to the system. When the last component in a process finishes, the process is classified as an empty process. The system may keep it alive as a form of caching, to speed up the restart of the app. Note that the system may also kill off a process that has live components. That's part of what the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) is about.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have updated the question please have a look

Comment: Thank you So much for you valuable time. Really nice explanation Thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more clarification please, will these two threads run in separate VM.

Comment: @JohnChristy - Each process will have a separate Dalvik VM. Each VM can support multiple threads.